# Slick Not working Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, carousel, slick.js

I manually added slick.js on my index.html. The Slick is working when I put my images manually. But when I put it on array and use *ngFor the slick is not responding.

```
    import { Component,OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
    declare var jQuery: any;


    @Component({
        selector: 'SlickCarousel',
        template:'

    <div class="carousel-block">
        <div class="slick">
            <div class="single-item" *ngIf="items">
            <!--template bindings={}-->
                <img *ngFor="#slickItem of items" src="theme/images/{{slickItem}}" alt="Pinoy BoybandPH">
            </div>   
        </div>

        <div class="upper-geometric">
            <img src="theme/images/geometric-upper-splash.png" alt="">
        </div>  


   ' })
    export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit{
        items = ['image1-splash.jpg','image2-splash.jpg','image3-splash.jpg'];
        slickItem = new Array();

    ngOnInit():any {
        jQuery('.single-item').slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: true,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplaySpeed: 5000,
            cssEase: 'linear'
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried `AfterViewInit` ?

Comment: wow AfterViewInit is working Thanks!